# Translate logo and favicon?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am wondering if there is a method to translate the appearance settings section for each theme, for example the logo URL.

Comment: To render in another language ?http://www.thefreedictionary.com/translate

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing - have different (translated) logos per language. Did you figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This "Variable Translation" module should help you out: http://drupal.org/node/1113374